# Dynamic styling of before pseudo element - Angular 5

Tags: css, angular

I am wondering, is there a way to style pseudo elements like `:before` using `[ngStyle]` or `[style.something]` ? I am getting some colors as I log in in my app and I use those colors to style some elements, so I don't want to use ngClass and css (colors are different depending on who logs in).

Any advice is welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't style them directly from your component, but you can create a CSS rule in your stylesheet with JS.

Once you get your colors :

```
let styleSheet = document.styleSheets[0];
styleSheet.insertRule(`.your-class:before { color: ${yourColor}; }`, styleSheet.cssRules.length);
```

This will add the rule at the end of your file (so applied last).

Be careful about view encapsulation though !